# c# Array.ForEach alternative that replaces elements

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, transform

Is there a standard function I can use that iterates over an array similarly to ForEach, applying a function to each element and replacing it in the array with the result?

Something like the following, but where dimension powers afterwards contains the results of IntPow(2, i) on each element.

```
dimensionPowers = Enumerable.Range(0, dimensions + 1).ToArray();
Array.ForEach(dimensionPowers,
    (i) => IntPow(2, i));
```

(I know I can iterate over the array with a for loop - I'm just wondering if there's a more concise alternative).

Comment: Can you override `dimensionPowers`? Does `dimensionPowers` have multiple pointers from different places?

Comment: Do you mean something like `ConvertAll` that returns new array based on some converter function?

Comment: dimensionPowers is just an int[]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MSDN docs says that the designers deliberately did not put in a "ForEach" with an Array due to the fact that: 1) it is trivial to write, 2) exactly your problem -- people will get confused whether the original array is modified or not.

Most of the ForEach types of array iterator implementation (you actually need a "map" function) returns a new instance of an array.  For example, you can use LINQ:

```
newArray = dimensionPowers.Select(i => IntPow(2,i)).ToArray();
```

or better:

```
dimensionPowers = Enumerable.Range(0, dimensions + 1).Select(i => IntPow(2,i)).ToArray();
```

However, if you want to modify the original array in-place, there is the good old for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < dimensionPowers.Length; i++) { dimensionPowers[i] = IntPow(2,i); }
```

The designers for .NET forces you to use these different methods just so that you'll know when an array is modified.

If you want to implement your in-place modification, you can create an extension method:

```
static void ForEachModifyInPlace<T> (this Array<T> array, Func<T,T> map_action) {
    for (int i=0; i < array.Length; i++) { array[i] = map_action(array[i]); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it much more concisely (using existing methods).

You could collapse the two steps in one:

```
dimensionPowers = Enumerable.Range(0, dimensions + 1).Select(i => IntPow(2, i)).ToArray();
```